# pd.read_table Error on String Parsing

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dataframe

Need help with an an IO error while Parsing a string I am trying to Write multiple Lines (in a string varaible) to a Pandas dataframe using Python.

my string FilteredText contains:
u'\nStrval1 294.25 4.10 1.41 290.15 2,589 7.62 7,043.65 305.70 230.55\nStrval2 1,059.00 10.85 1.04 1,048.15 1,676 17.75 9,624.39 1,319.95 915.20.. [followed by BULK LINES of DATA]

I am trying to use read_table ( also tried read_csv)
df = pd.read_table(FilteredText, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["COL1", "COL2", "COL3",,..])

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read

parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, self.options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, kwds)
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source <br/>
**IOError: File**
```

I have also tried using read_csv
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(FilteredText), delim_whitespace=True,

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

For me your last solution working:

```
FilteredText=u'\nStrval1 294.25 4.10 1.41 290.15 2,589 7.62 7,043.65 305.70 230.55\nStrval2 1,059.00 10.85 1.04 1,048.15 1,676 17.75 9,624.39 1,319.95 915.20'
n = list('abcdefghij')
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(FilteredText), delim_whitespace=True, names=n)
print (df)

         a         b      c     d         e      f      g         h         i  \
0  Strval1    294.25   4.10  1.41    290.15  2,589   7.62  7,043.65    305.70   
1  Strval2  1,059.00  10.85  1.04  1,048.15  1,676  17.75  9,624.39  1,319.95   

        j  
0  230.55  
1  915.20
```

Comment: Thanks for this, However read_csv only processes the first 50 Rows.

Comment: @suraj_Blore - Why do you think there was only `50` rows processes, how it was verified? Maybe some problem in data?

Comment: I have checked that side, Nothing Different in Row number 51 , No special Characters.   Also, I could not find any warning to troubleshoot.

Comment: Very interestingly, when I try to debug it using "python -m pdb <Pythonfile>.py  It processes ALL the rows,  Really amazing.

Comment: Maybe problem your output show only first rows, if check `print (df.tail(20))` it return last rows?

Comment: Tried that as well. The length of df is also 50... Further, I have rechecked the Data again as well.

Answer (score 0):

This IS resolved. I have found another approach to parse my data.

Would like to thank jezrael for his timely responses.